# file_put_contents with name of the client and actual date

Tags: php

I would like to save the pdf that is generated inside my server with different names depending on the client and the actual date.

```
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents("pedidos/saved.pdf", $pdf);
```

Actually is working but instead of using **saved.pdf** as the name of the file, I would like it to be the name of the client and the actual date.  For example **cocacola26-11-2012.pdf**
I have the name of the client inside **$nombrecliente**.  I have tried to do it in many ways without success. Thanks.

Comment: many ways like what? have you tried `"pedidos/saved$nombreclient.pdf"` for instance?

Comment: I have just done it and the name of the pdf now is savedArray.pdf

Comment: then $nombrecliente is an array. try to do var_dump($nombrecliente);

Comment: @user1757383 is $nombreclient an array?

Comment: This is how I get the name of the client:  
$sql = "SELECT nombrecliente FROM cliente WHERE id_cliente = '$id_cliente'";
$rs = mysql_query($sql, $conexio) or die("Error al consultar: ".mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_row($rs);
$nombrecliente=$row[0];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents('pedidos/' . $nombrecliente . date('m-d-Y'). '.pdf', $pdf);
```

Comment: I just read that you posted $nombrecliente was an array. Obviously you need to find out which key is holding the name and use that. E.g.: `$nombrecliente['name']`

Comment: Ok now is working.  I already get the name of the client and the date.  But one last question Why I only can save one file in the folder.  It dosen´t let me more than one.   I have to erase the one in the server so I can put a new one.